# Is there a way to write markdown in Mathematica notebook?

Tags: notebooks, input-forms

Whenever I want to take notes and do calculation at the same time in `Mathematica Notebook`, I found it's annoying to change the style of the cell and typesetting with mouse kept clicking around.

Is there a third-party package supporting us to write markdown language directly in `Mathematica Notebook`? so that we can use `Mathematica notebook` in an elegant way like using `Jupyter Notebook`, which let us get rid of using mouse and large amounts of shortcuts.

---

I think `Jupyter Notebook` and `Mathematica Notebook` work in the similar way.
Writing texts and running code at one place.

before running
[image]
after running

[image]

Comment: You can use the keyboard shortcuts to change the styles. Alt+7 switch current cell to text-cell style which is good for any comments.

Comment: So my guess is that it is possible but not in the same form, that is without taking care of anything. The reason is that `#` and `##` are already special for a parser.

Comment: I think `StyleKeyMapping` is your friend here. I use it in my notebook-to-markdown stylesheet to switch between cell styles conveniently, for example.