# How to markdown parts of input expressions?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, input-forms

Is there a way to manually tag parts of input expressions to highlight the part?

A wrapper function that only affects input cell and is otherwise transparent to evaluation?

For example, would like to have a function such as:

```
 Query[All, highlightedInput[Median] /* f][<|"a" -> {1, 2}, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}|>]
```

Where `Median` would be highlighted - analogous to `Highlighted` for output form - but `highlightedInput` would not appear in the input cell. Application is instructional material where one wants some parts highlighted.

Could only find a related Q but doesn't get to a solution: [Is there a way to write markdown in Mathematica notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152302/801)

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155180/5478?

Comment: @Kuba, yes that works, wasn't aware of evaluate in place. You can close this Q.

Comment: The accepted answer to the referenced question doesn't produce an input where the highlighted part is transparent to evaluation.

Comment: @CarlWoll, I had tried a couple of examples and it seemed to be transparent. Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: I added a comparison in my answer to the referenced question showing the difference in evaluation behavior.

Comment: @CarlWoll - that's interesting. Let me ask Kuba.

Comment: @Kuba, can you address Carl's addendum?

Comment: @CarlWoll, substituting `SameQ` for `Equal` yields True with `Defer`. And weirdly, wrapping both in `Hold // FullForm` shows no sign of the highlighting/framed.

Comment: @CarlWoll and alan, the best method depends of what exactly is the use case. I agree Carl's method avoids `StripOnInput->False` which my does not (as it wasn't originally meant to be evaluated). Otoh one can use `RawBoxes @ FrameBox[ToBoxes @ Defer[1 +1]]` with my method (in place of `Framed[Defer[1+1]]`. Does not look neat but gives you flexibility  to do whatever you want while for Carl's solution you only have predefined aliases. Both have a downside of a need to write box expressions by hand (fixable too) so as I said, depends what one needs.

Comment: @Kuba, do you know why `SameQ` and `Equal` behave differently, given the same `FullForm`? Is the distinction due to `StripOnInput`?

Comment: @alancalvitti not sure, can't check now, will try tomorrow. Btw, to see what is behind it hit Ctrl+Shift+E because evaluation, even with FullForm, will strip what is not StripOnInput->False.